# Python throws json.decoder.JSONDecodeError when trying to work with non-json dataset

Tags: json, python-3.x, regex

I am calling a server application which returns a non-json response. I wrote the code below but I still get an error.

I am trying to fix the invalid JSON issues using REGEX first before passing it to the json.loads method but get json.decoder.JSONDecodeError error

I have improved the code based on John Williams response by applying following rules however, just struggling to get the last rule implemented i.e. injecting the comma at the right places.

Looks like all ‘{‘ -> ‘:{‘ , all ‘}’ -> ‘},’ unless followed by ‘}’ , all ‘name:’ -> ‘“name”’, and **all ‘“name”:”value”’ -> ‘“name”:”value”,’ unless followed by ‘}’**.

```
import re

input_str = '''id {
    type : "type"
    timestamp : "timestamp"
}
batters {
    batter {
        regular : "regular"
        chocolate: "chocolate"
        blueberry : "blueberry"
    }
    ack {}
}
'''

pattern = r'(\w+)(?=\s*:)|(\w+)(?=\s*{)|(\s*:\s*)|(".*?":\s*".*?")(?!})(?!,)'

def replace(match):
    if match.group(1):
        return f'"{match.group(1)}":'
    elif match.group(2):
        return f'"{match.group(2)}": {{'
    elif match.group(3):
        return ':'
    elif match.group(4):
        return f'{match.group(4)}, '
    else:
        return '},'

output_str = re.sub(pattern, replace, input_str)
new_str = output_str.replace("::",":")
sec_str = new_str.replace("{ {","{")
print('{' + sec_str + '}')
```

Generated JSON :

```
{"id": {
    "type":"type"
    "timestamp":"timestamp"
}
"batters": {
    "batter": {
        "regular":"regular"
        "chocolate":"chocolate"
        "blueberry":"blueberry"
    }
    "ack": {}
}
}
```

Also, wondering if anyone has used decorator to address this issue i.e. decorator method which fixes the invalid JSON issues

Comment: What does the json look like that fails?

Comment: Thanks John, update the question (with latest code changes) and output JSON.

Comment: This server... is it following some standard data serialize protocol? Does it tell you what the return format is?

Comment: This doesn't look much like JSON and I don't see trying to coerce it into JSON is going to be successful. You really need a parser for the data.

Comment: The generated json isn’t valid json. It the incoming data formatted to any known standard? Perhaps there is a parser?

Comment: I am dealing with a legacy application which generates a bespoke output, so I am looking to format invalid json, process it and send to a microservice.

Comment: Writing a converter with regex is absolutely doable. Looks like all ‘{‘ -> ‘:{‘ , all ‘}’ -> ‘},’ unless followed by ‘}’ , all ‘name:’ -> ‘“name”’, and all ‘“name”:”value”’ -> ‘“name”:”value”,’ unless followed by ‘}’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code that works based on John Williams input:

```
import json
import re

# Define the input string
input_str = '''id {
    type : "type"
    timestamp : "timestamp"
}
batters {
    batter {
        regular : "regular"
        chocolate: "chocolate"
        blueberry : "blueberry"
    }
    ack {}
}
'''

# Define the regular expression pattern for replacement
pattern = r'(\w+)(?=\s*:)|(\w+)(?=\s*{)|(\s*:\s*)|(".*?":\s*".*?")(?!})(?!,)'

# Define the replacement function
def replace(match):
    if match.group(1):
        return f'"{match.group(1)}":'
    elif match.group(2):
        return f'"{match.group(2)}": {{'
    elif match.group(3):
        return ':'
    elif match.group(4):
        return f'{match.group(4)}, '
    else:
        return '},'

# Apply the replacement logic using re.sub() method
output_str = re.sub(pattern, replace, input_str)
new_str = output_str.replace("::",":")
sec_str = new_str.replace("{ {","{")
# Print the output string
#print('{' + sec_str + '}')

processed_str = '{' + sec_str + '}'

pattern = r'("[^"]+":"[^"]+")(?!\s*})'

# Define the replacement function
def replace(match):
    return f'{match.group(1)},'

# Apply the replacement logic using re.sub() method
output_str = re.sub(pattern, replace, processed_str)

# Print the output string
print(output_str)

print("==========================")

# Define the regular expression pattern for replacement
pattern = r'"(\w+)":"(\w+)"(?!\s*[},])'

# Define the replacement function
def replace(match):
    return f'"{match.group(1)}":"{match.group(2)}",'

# Apply the replacement logic using re.sub() method
output_str = re.sub(pattern, replace, output_str)

# Inject commas after '}' if it's not followed by another '}'
output_str = re.sub(r'}(?!\s*[}])', '},', output_str)

# Print the output string
print(output_str)

print("------------------------------")

# Define the regular expression pattern for replacement
pattern = r'(.*),\s*\n*\s*}'

# Define the replacement function
def replace(match):
    return match.group(1) + '\n}'

# Apply the replacement logic using re.sub() method
output_str = re.sub(pattern, replace, output_str)

# Print the output string
print(output_str[:-1])

json_data = json.loads(output_str[:-1])
print(json_data)
print(type(json_data))
print(json_data["batters"]["batter"]["regular"])
```

Output:

```
    {"id": {
    "type":"type",
    "timestamp":"timestamp"
}
"batters": {
    "batter": {
        "regular":"regular",
        "chocolate":"chocolate",
        "blueberry":"blueberry"
    }
    "ack": {}
}
}
==========================
{"id": {
    "type":"type",
    "timestamp":"timestamp"
},
"batters": {
    "batter": {
        "regular":"regular",
        "chocolate":"chocolate",
        "blueberry":"blueberry"
    },
    "ack": {}
}
},
------------------------------
{"id": {
    "type":"type",
    "timestamp":"timestamp"
},
"batters": {
    "batter": {
        "regular":"regular",
        "chocolate":"chocolate",
        "blueberry":"blueberry"
    },
    "ack": {}
}
}
{'id': {'type': 'type', 'timestamp': 'timestamp'}, 'batters': {'batter': {'regular': 'regular', 'chocolate': 'chocolate', 'blueberry': 'blueberry'}, 'ack': {}}}
<class 'dict'>
regular
```